# Cannot reach vba code after Userform X-Button modification

Tags: excel, vba

I inserted

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
unload me
thisworkbook.close
End Sub
```

into my userform1. I actually have 3 buttons on that form but after inserting the code above the workbook closes after clicking on any of these buttons. Any idea how i can reach my vba-editor now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as far as I understand you created macro in userform which always closes this workbook - pretty unlucky :)

It is easy way out of it. Turn on VB Editor in any Excel file and run this code:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

This will turn off of executing any events, so it will not close your workbook anymore. After you are done editing your code you can easily turn it on by running this code:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: yeah... another problem is, the userform gets executed on the workbook.open event. So i cannot enter the editor all i see is the userform and the excelsheet in the background. i can only click the userform but on all buttons the workbook closes. so i cannot even put your code in the editor ;(

Comment: Put it in blank excel sheet and execute it. It will have an efect on all excel documents you are going to open. That is why you should later enable it for good work of your Excel.

Comment: if anyone else reads... when the form opens, press ctrl + break....... that stops the code from running.